# How do I notify all threads waiting on other monitor?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, monitor

Let's say you have a bank account. You have two synchronized methods

```
public synchronized void withdraw ( int amount, String name ) {
    while ( account_balance < amount ) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }

}

public synchronized void deposit ( int amount, String name ) {
     while ( account_balance > 3*amount ) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

}
```

Threads that wait in withdraw monitor are waiting for another thread to deposit some money  so they can withdraw and vice versa. So it makes no sense notifying all threads in withdraw monitor if one thread withdraws money, it makes sense to notify threads that are waiting in deposit monitor cause account balance is "full" and vice versa. Since you can't specify which thread wakes up with notify() and notifyAll() notifies threads waiting in the current monitor how does one notify threads that are waiting on some other monitor?

Comment: Why don't you synchronize on a different object?

Comment: Use a [`Lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html) from the new concurrency API.

Comment: you need to call `notifyAll()` on the object for which these methods are called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock instead of using the language's built-in monitors?

```
class Account {
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition depositOk = lock.newCondition();
    private final Condition withdrawOk = lock.newCondition();

    public void withdraw(amount) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (!accountContainsAtLeast(amount)) {
                withdrawOk.await();
            }
            withdrawLocked(amount);
            depositOK.signal();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void deposit(amount) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (!OKtoDeposit(amount)) {
                depositOk.await();
            }
            depositLocked(amount);
            withdrawOK.signal();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was taught of having a try block inside a while loop but you did it on the contrary. What's the difference and what's better in your opinion?

Comment: @Larper, Whether you should handle an exception inside a loop or not is a whole separate topic, and the answer will depend on design choices and the needs of the application.  In this case though, the try block does not _handle_ an exception at all.  The purpose of the try blocks in my example are to insure that, no matter what else happens, the mutex will be unlocked before the method returns.

Answer (score 0):

> notifyAll() notifies threads waiting in the current monitor

No it doesn't. It notifies all threads that are waiting on the monitor you call it on. It is exactly what you want.

Comment: @Larper wants deposit() to wake only those threads that are waiting in withdraw() and vice versa.  Doesn't want deposit() to wake other depositors or withdraw() to wake other withdrawers.

Comment: @jameslarge If that's the issue, two monitors would solve it, which is why he is asking about 'some other monitor'.

Comment: @Larper, Using two monitors might sound like a solution, but I'm not sure you could actually make it work without risking "lost" notifications.  Also, don't forget, you need a mutex to prevent threads from seeing the account in an inconsistent state.  Trying to juggle _three_ monitors would get ugly.  The Lock objects in the java.util.concurrent package (see my answer) allows any number of independent conditions to be associated with one mutex which cleanly solves your problem.